# Access properties from class that contains 2 models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to add 2 models in 1 view. I made a class that contains both classes:

```
public class Models
{
    public IEnumerable<Model1> model1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Model2> model2 { get; set; }
}
```

in my View I set the model:

```
@model Models
```

and when I try to access some data from the first model, for example after writing the model, it gives me List methods only, instead of accessing the model's properties.
I want when I write `model1.Name` to be able to access the property `Name` from the model `model1`.
I get that is a list class but how can I access the properties from the models?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your properties are collection (`IEnumerable`), so how do you suppose to access the properties directly. You need to loop through the properties as shown below.

```
@model Models

@foreach(var item in Model.model1)
{
    @item.Name
}

@foreach(var item in Model.model2)
{
    @item.Name
}
```

Comment: So how can I access the properties in this example:
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

Comment: Then why did you make your properties IEnumerable, simply use public Model1{get;set;}

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just coppied from a post about multiple models in one view and didn't pay attention to the model... :X

Comment: Now when I try to create a new user with the "model1" class I get this error:
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.model1', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Hotel_Reservations_Manager.Models.Models'.